# Tangent line of Lissajous curve?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, parametric

I'm trying to find at how many points the tangent line of $(\cos(3t),\sin(2t))$ goes through the point $(3,0)$.

My attempt:
This is the same thing as saying for how many values of $t$ do we have $x'(t)+3=0$ and $y'(t)=0$. So solving for $t$ in the system $(-k(3\sin(3t)+3), k 2\cos(2t))=(0,0)$. From the second equation we have $t=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi m$. So we need to find when does $\sin(3t)=1$. So wouldn't $t=0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

But plotting the function shows there are at least four points where the tangent line intersects $(3,0)$. Did I make a mistake in my calculuation?

Comment: Your conditions $x'(t) + 3 = 0$ and $y'(t) = 0$ do not take into account the location $p = \bigl(x(t), y(t)\bigr)$, so they're unlikely to be a correct characterization of tangent lines at $p$. :)

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. $p=(3,0)$ is fixed and not on the curve. Could you explain more?

Comment: What you might try is 1. Write down a parametric description of the tangent line at a general point $p = \bigl(x(t_{0}), y(t_{0})\bigr)$ of the curve; 2. impose the condition that $q = (3, 0)$ lie on the line you found in 1. (Your system finds points where $x'(t) = -3$ and $y'(t) = 0$, which is not a tangency condition for your curve.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plotted this, too, and confirm that there appear to be four tangents that pass through $(3,0)$.

Gradient of tangent is given by: $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}=\frac {2 \cos 2t}{-3 \sin 3t}$

Equation of tangent is given by: $y=-\frac {2 \cos 2t}{3 \sin 3t}x+c$

Use the known point $\left(\cos 3t, \sin 2t \right)$ to find $c$

$\sin 2t=-\frac {2 \cos 2t}{3 \sin 3t}\cos 3t+c$

$c=\sin 2t+\frac {2 \cos 2t \cos 3t}{3 \sin 3t}$

Equation of tangent is therefore: $y=-\frac {2 \cos 2t}{3 \sin 3t}x+\sin 2t+\frac {2 \cos 2t \cos 3t}{3 \sin 3t}$

Set $x=3$ and $y=0$ to have:

$0=-\frac {2 \cos 2t}{\sin 3t}+\sin 2t+\frac {2 \cos 2t \cos 3t}{3 \sin 3t}$

$0=-6 \cos 2t+3 \sin 2t \sin 3t+2 \cos 2t \cos 3t$

Try using trig identities: $\sin 3t \equiv 3 \sin t - 4 \sin ^3 t$, $\cos 3t \equiv 4 \cos ^3 t -3 \cos t$, $\sin 2t \equiv 2 \sin t \cos t$, $\cos 2t \equiv 2 \cos ^2 t - 1$

$0=-12 \cos ^2 t + 6 +6 \sin t \cos t(3 \sin t - 4 \sin ^3 t)+2 (2 \cos ^2 t - 1)(4 \cos ^3 t -3 \cos t)$

$0=-12 \cos ^2 t + 6 + 18 (1-\cos^2 t)\cos t - 24 (1-\cos^2 t)^2 \cos t+16 \cos ^5 t - 20 \cos ^3 t +6 \cos t$

$0=-12 \cos ^2 t + 6 + 18 \cos t-18 \cos^3 t - 24 \cos t +48\cos^3 t-24\cos^5 t+16 \cos ^5 t - 20 \cos ^3 t +6 \cos t$

$0=-8 \cos ^5 t +10\cos^3 t -12 \cos ^2 t +6$

$0=4 \cos ^5 t -5  \cos^3 t + 6 \cos ^2 t - 3$

If $z=\cos t$, then $4z^5-5z^3+6z^2-3=0$

There are potentially five roots to this polynomial. A sketch shows that there are three roots.

Only two are suitable as a cosine, so that gives two values of $\cos t$. For each value of $\cos t$ there are two possible values of $t$, giving a total of four tangents.

Comment: After working through it, I also got that answer. But then I plotted it in wolfram alpha and it said there were 6 roots?

Comment: Yes, but two of those roots are outside [-Pi,Pi]. Actually, there are an infinite number of roots, but they only correspond to a finite number of points since both sin and cos are sinusoidal.

Comment: Oh, right right. For some reason I was thinking the domain was [-2pi,2pi] instead of [0,2pi]. Is there any way to find exact solutions to this? I've tried a few trig identities and guessing, but it's not budging. I should probably just settle with the Wolfram solutions...

Comment: I guess a better question: Is there a way without using Wolfram to tell that there are only 4 points on $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: WA will give you an exact solution too, but it's the arctangent of a root of an irreducible 5th degree polynomial, so that's not really helpful. Are you allowed to graph the function to determine the number of roots (note that they don't ask for the *values* of the roots, just the number) and/or use numerical approximation techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a given value of t, you can compute several quantities including x(t), y(t), x'(t), y'(t). Using these values, can you find the slope for the curve at a given value of t (hint: chain rule).

Since you then have the slope and a point on the tangent line (namely (x(t),y(t))), you can derive the formula for the tangent line.

Then, simply solve to see which values of t give you a line that passes through (3,0).

Comment: Wait, why do I need the chain rule? I would think the slope would be given by $\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$

Comment: Well, yes, but that's because of the chain rule: dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)